# When opened with google chrome, html code is shown as text

Tags: html

The below html code was in a notepad text editor. Saved and then opened the file using google chrome. However it showed the same code only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <title> HTML Cheat sheet</title>
     </head>     

     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
I did save as .html
However when i opened the using chrome it comes as url....html.txt
I think the .html i saved as was used as filename.html.txt where txt is the only extension. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: did you saved it as a .html file ?

Comment: Does the file have a `.txt` or `.html` extension? Be aware that some operating systems may hide the real extension.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <title> HTML Cheat sheet</title>
     </head>     

     <body>
  This is body
     </body>
</html>

It will be must work if you save .html

Comment: *think the .html i saved as was used as filename.html.txt where txt is the only extension. Any idea how to resolve it?* — [Make sure you can see file extensions](https://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml) then rename the file, and get yourself a better editor than Notepad (VS Code is popular at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please save the file with .html extension like **index.html** then open it chrome
I think you do not save file in **.html** format

I think the problem is, you have saved your file like **index.html.txt** format so this is main problem, please rename it like **index.html.txt** to **index.html** (remove .txt). This is html extension **.html** format and also i think in your computer **hide extension** so you do not see this extension so show it and rename it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <title> HTML Cheat sheet</title>
     </head>     

     <body>
     This is body
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried that too.

Comment: @Power123 i understand your problem, You have saved your file like index.html.txt format so this is main problem, please rename it like index.html.txt to index.html (remove .txt). This is html extension .html format and also i think in your computer hide extension so you do not see this extension so show it and rename it

Comment: Not the fact. The file can be saved normally, but still could be opened as a text, I have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the file as a .html

Open text editor copy the code and from Files dropdown on the top left corner click Save As and save your file as a WebPage.html

Answer (score 0):

> REMEMBER: While always saving a program file of any programming language save it with it's respective extension: Like (.html) for HTML files and (.py) for python files. If you forget to save then your system opens the file with the default notepad.

Now go to (Save as...) and edit the extension from **.txt** or other extension to **.html**

Comment: Yes. I saved it as .html but when i open in chrome the link is .....html.txt

Comment: Did you remove the .txt before adding .html? Even after making the changes if you are facing the same problem you can attach the screenshot of how you saved it.

Comment: I created a new text file in desktop and saved it. removed everything, named for example: test.html                                                                                                                Then when i opened it using chrome, what happened was that in the url, the location, then ended with filename: ....../test.html.txt

Comment: I think so , that file might be a duplicate copy of your original file. Copy your code, delete the file and open a new notepad and paste the code with the proper extension and save it and then run it.

Comment: Or in your save as... There will be a drop-down called save as type... See if there is an option called.html and if so convert it to .html